# Alamofire and cocoapods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, osx-yosemite, alamofire

I'm trying to get my code to link on OS 10.10.3 and XCode 6.3 with Alamofire. My podfile looks like this:

```
platform :osx, '10.10'
use_frameworks!

target 'worth2' do
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2'
end
```

When I go to build my project though, I end up with

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Versions/A/Alamofire   Referenced from:
>   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/worth2-bskxhwsefwbntgeikvunyfjphixk/Build/Products/Debug/[project-name]
>   Reason: image not found

I've looked at [what sounds like the same issue](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/101) but it seems like that's for an older version of XCode. Under Targets -> Build Phases -> Target Dependencies, I'm unable to add the frameworks. Apple frameworks show up but not my two libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed setting the source to cocoapods specs.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```